# introduce line break at the same position based on another file

Tags: awk, perl

I have 3 input files all having the same number of lines. I have come up with a movie example to make the question look interesting.

*file1.txt -- Essentially contains the actor names.*

```
1234|jacknicholson|actor
5678|jacknicholson|director
4321|christianbale|actor
```

*file2.txt -- Contains the movies of the actors.*

```
1234|oneflewovercuckoosnest^asgoodasitgets
5678|theshining
4321|batmanbegins^darkknight
```

*file3.txt -- Residence of the actors.*

```
1234|california
5678|hollywoodstudios
4321|losangeles
```

I am splitting the first input file based on the condition that if names are equal, I need to apply some algorithm. The command is as below.

```
awk -F '|' 'NR>1 && $2 != prev {print ""} {prev=$2; print}' file1.txt
```

The above command will make my first file (`file1.txt`) as,

```
1234|jacknicholson|actor
5678|jacknicholson|director

4321|christianbale|actor
```

I need to introduce the space at the same position in the remaining 2 files too so that I can apply my algorithm.

One approach that comes to my mind is, store the position of spaces in the `file1.txt` in an array and then when I encounter that position in the remaining 2 files, introduce the spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To introduce a blank line in a file at the same position as changes in actors in `file1.txt`, try:

```
$ awk -F '|' '{save=$0; getline<"file1.txt"} NR>1 && $2!=prev {print ""} {prev=$2; print save}' file2.txt
1234|oneflewovercuckoosnest^asgoodasitgets
5678|theshining

4321|batmanbegins^darkknight
```

The above works quite a bit like your code except that it is extended to read two files at the same time.  It reads from `file2.txt` and saves the line in the variable `save`.  If then reads from `file.txt`, and using the same logic as your code, determines if the actor changes and, if so, prints a line break.  It then prints the line it received from `file2.txt`.

Comment: I will check this solution as soon as I get into the server. Thanks a lot for providing a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{if(!NF){a[FNR]=1}next}a[FNR]{print"\n"$0;next}{print}' file1.txt file2.txt
1234|oneflewovercuckoosnest^asgoodasitgets
5678|theshining

4321|batmanbegins^darkknight
```

- When reading `file1.txt`, we mark the line number in array `a` if line
  is blank.
- When reading `file2.txt`, we get line number which is blank in array
  `a` and print a blank line before it. For other lines, we print it normally.

Comment: Thanks for another `awk` solution. It also worked as expected :)